# Pandoc: Is there a way to generate <kbd> tag?

Tags: pandoc

I love Pandoc's way of creating inline `<code>` using back ticks. Is there a similar possibility to create `<kbd>` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any HTML `<key>` tag...

However, generally speaking: you can

- either write [raw HTML](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#raw-html) interspersed in the markdown.
- or write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that changes pandoc `code` elements to some raw HTML (then you can just use backticks), or narrow it down on only those with a certain class (e.g. `` my text `my key contents`{.key} ``)

Comment: You're right, I meant the `<kbd>` tag. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim glad I could help, feel free to accept the answer then...

Answer (score 0):

Example of lua-filter to produce `<kbd>F1</kbd>` from `~Shift+F2~`.

```lua
function Superscript (element)
  return pandoc.Span(element.content, {class = 'kbd'})
end
```

(if need to place that into file `kbd.lua` than you can use it adding `--lua-filter=kbd.lua` to pandoc command line)